# ''Naively holomorphic'' function on a closed disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a complex function defined on a closed disk $\overline{D}$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that $f(z)$ is differentiable at any point $z$ in $\overline{D}$. That is to say, the limit
$$
\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{f(z) - f(z_0)}{z-z_0}
$$
exists for all $z_0$ in $\overline{D}$.

**My question:** Is there a holomorphic extension of $f(z)$ which is defined on an open set containing $\overline{D}$? How about other (real) surfaces with boundary embedded in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the limit above; do you mean the limit when $z+\Delta z$ is in the disc too? Usually holomorphic function on the closed disc means by definition holomorphic in an open neighborhood but I guess you want something different

Comment: Yes, I am using the usual $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ as the definition of the limit. I know the title is confusing, but I could not find a good one

Comment: The answer then is no; wlog we can assume we are on the unit disc (change $z\to z/r$ otherwise); using that $|x^n -y^n| \le n|x-y|$ when $|x|, |y| \le 1$ it is very easy to see that any power series $\sum a_nz^n$ for which $\sum n|a_n|< \infty$ satisfies the required property with the limit being the expected one so $\sum na_nz^{n-1}$ But now pick any power series with the unit circle as natural boundary (eg $\sum z^{2^n}$ ) and integrate it a few times so coefficients satisfy the relation mentioned hence the property in the OP; the integrated function has the unit circle as natural boundary

Comment: @Conrad We need to take a good power series so that analytic continuation is not possible, right? I am struggling to see how integration changes the possibility or not (maybe I am asking a different question)

Comment: If a power series is not continuable at a point on the circle any antiderivative of any order is not continuable either (otherwise its derivatives of any order so including the original power series would be continuable too); however for any power series with bounded coefficients say, the second antiderivative is absolutely convergent on the closed unit disc (as coefficients get divided by $n(n+1)$) so the third antiderivative satisfies the required coefficient property to ensure that the limit you want exists everywhere

Comment: @Conrad Oh, I somehow forgot analyticity. I understand it now, thank you for your clear answer! ''Naive holomorphicity'' on non-open sets doesn't work at all, then...

Comment: posted an explicit answer extending the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f$ is holomorphic on the unit disc (implied by the hypothesis - as noted by a change of variable we can assume we are on the unit disc) and st $f$ is also differentiable on the boundary when we approach it from within the closed unit disc; in other words $\lim_{\delta \to 0}\frac{f(z+\delta)-f(z)}{\delta}$ exists as long as $z, z+\delta \in \mathbb {\overline{D}}$.

Then $f$ can still have the unit circle as natural boundary so be as far as it can from having analytic extension beyond the open unit disc.

The generic condition for which the limit above exists at least a.e. is $f' \in H^1$ the Hardy space of the unit disc, but this requires a little theory while it is quite easy to show that if $f' \in B$ the Wiener algebra of absolutely convergent power series on the unit disc then $\lim_{\delta \to 0}\frac{f(z+\delta)-f(z)}{\delta}=f'(z)$ whenever $z, z+\delta \in \mathbb {\overline{D}}$,  where here $f'$ also extends to the boundary by continuity since its power series is absolutely convergent

However absolute convergence of the power series is easily obtained without modifying analytic continuation at the boundary - for example assume $h$ has bounded coefficients and has the unit circle as natural boundary; then (any) second antiderivative $h_2, h_2''=h$ of $h$ is in the Wiener algebra since its Taylor coefficients are $\frac{h_n}{(n+1)(n+2)}$ which form an absolutely convergent series if $|h_n| \le M$; so a third antiderivative $f, f'=h_2$ satisfies the above condition hence $\lim_{\delta \to 0}\frac{f(z+\delta)-f(z)}{\delta}=f'(z)$ whenever $z, z+\delta \in \mathbb {\overline{D}}$

But clearly, $f,h, f'''=h$ are continuable at the same points on the unit circle so if we choose any $h$ with bounded coefficients and unit circle as natural boundary (eg $\sum z^{2^{n}}$) we get an $f$ with the unit circle as natural boundary but differentiable from inside on the boundary too.

Repeating the procedure we can get $f$ differentiable $n$ times on the boundary from the inside and with a bit more care even infinitely many times and still with natural boundary the unit circle (here the antiderivative method doesn't quite work but one can choose coefficients carefully so we still have natural boundary the whole circle and now all derivatives are in the Wiener algebra)

As for the claim about $f' \in B$ implying the boundary derivative of $f$ exists and is the limit of $f'$ this follows by a standard argument using the crucial inequality $|x^n-y^n| \le n|x-y|, |x|, |y| \le 1$ which follows by factoring $x^n-y^n$ and noting that each of the $n$ terms in the second factor is bounded by $1$.

Then with $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n, f'(z)=\sum na_nz^{n-1}, \sum n|a_n| <M$, picking $\epsilon >0$  and $n_{\epsilon}$ st $\sum_{n \ge n_{\epsilon}} n|a_n| < \epsilon$ we have by using the power series, absolute convergence and the inequality above (here it is crucial of course that $|z+\delta| \le 1$ so $|z+\delta|^n-|z^n| \le n\delta$) we get  $$|f(z+\delta)-f(z)-\delta f'(z)| \le \sum_{n < n_{\epsilon}}(a_n(z+\delta)^n-a_nz^n-\delta na_nz^{n-1})+2\delta \epsilon$$

Now $n_{\epsilon}$ is fixed so we can find $\delta_0$ small enough so each of those first $n_{\epsilon}$ terms are small eg $\epsilon/n_{\epsilon}$ whenever $\delta < \delta_0$ and uniformly here in $|z| \le 2$ say since we have just polynomials now, so  $$|f(z+\delta)-f(z)-\delta f'(z)| \le 3\delta \epsilon, \delta <\delta_0, |z| \le 1, |z+\delta| \le 1$$ which implies the claim that $f$ is differentiable on the boundary from the inside and its derivative is the derivative of $f$ extended to the unit circle by the absolutely convergent power series

Comment: This result gives me the following problem: what if $f(z)$ is ''differentiable'' as many times as we want? This assumption may be enough to extend, I will study.

Comment: it's still the same - by the Gap theorem of Ostrowski Hadamard any lacunary ($a_n \ne 0$ only for a sequence $n_{j+1}/n_j >\delta>1$ eg $\sum a_nz^n, a_n \ne 0$ only for $n=2^m$)  power series with radius of convergence $1$ has the unit circle as natural boundary so choosing coefficients $a_n$ for which that happens but also $n^ka_n \to 0, n \to \infty$ for any $k$, eg $a_n=e^{-\sqrt n}$ and making a lacunary series like $f(z)=\sum a_{2^m}z^{2^m}$ gives $f$ infinitely differentiable on the unit circle from inside but not continuable anywhere

Comment: Amazing, monodromy around a point seems to be important for analytic functions, then. I appreciate your help!